# Nuget Installation Failed

Tags: c#, nuget

I am trying to install Nuget to Visual Studio 2013, but unfortunately it gives me the following error. Has anyone encountered the same issue?

[image]

Here is the log report:

> VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not
>   installable on any currently installed products.
>          at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Comment: Which version of VS.Net is this? It's saying that you have an incompatible "SKU" - A SKU is a product version as such, so sub-versions of VS presumably don't support certain tools.

Comment: Express edition does not support extensions, but afaik NuGet comes preinstalled.

Comment: I have the professional edition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 comes with the NuGet package manager pre-installed and can therefore not be installed manually.

Comment: Thanks aesvitas. I have seen nuget packages pre-installed